# Magento - How to get all orders except the ones with specific status

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and i am working on a custom extension.

Here is what code i use to select all orders with specific status:

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete'); ?>
```

How can i select all orders except the ones with specfic status?

Here is the complete code where i use the code shown above:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete') ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info');?>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()): ?>
<table class="data-table orders" id="my-orders-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="number"><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th class="date"><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th class="ship"><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>
            <th class="total"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th class="status"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th class="view">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="number"><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td class="date"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td class="ship"><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td class="total"><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td class="status"><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center view">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have placed no orders.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'complete')); ?>
```

Or when you have multiple statuses

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('nin' => array('pending','complete'))); ?>
```

Comment: @TonyStark That's odd It works for me. What kind of error you get. Maybe the error is  related to available memory in PHP

Comment: @TonyStark try add 
addAttributeToSelect('\*') for example
 $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('\*') ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'complete')); ?>

Comment: @TonyStark  it would be useful if you check your PHP error log.

Comment: Where i can find that? I receive a blank page without any error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117316/discussion-between-pawel-dubiel-and-tony-stark).

Comment: Hey can you please check this out? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125753/adminhtml-how-to-hide-orders-with-specific-status

Comment: @PawelDubiel Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334

Answer (score 1):

You can use "not equals":

```
...->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => 'thestatus'));
```

Comment: Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334 @Stuart

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'complete')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

to get status of cancelled orders

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'canceled');

foreach ($orders as $order) {
   echo $order->getStatus();
}
```

to get the status of processing orders

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'processing');

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
       echo $order->getStatus();
    }
```

Just change the order status to get the details of respective orders
also you can get all the order data from $order object